# Getting "SharePoint Workspace error : Class not registered" while syncing document library using Sync option

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, sync

When I tried to sync document library for offline work. I am getting

**"SharePoint Workspace error : Class not registered"**

[image]